# Mutt - Could not connect to smtp.gmail.com (Interrupted system call)

Tags: email, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, mutt

Thought I would try out Mutt on Ubuntu and after trying to get it to work for a couple days now I'm stuck on this error.

```
Could not connect to smtp.gmail.com (Interrupted system call).
```

I've looked all over the internet trying to figure out how to fix it but I can't find anything that will fix it. The `~/.mutt` and `~/.mutt/cache/` folders are created. I don't think there's an issue with msmtp because it's not adding anything to the log file.

here's my `.muttrc` without my passwords of course:

```
set imap_user = "<my_email>@gmail.com"
set imap_pass = "<my_password>"
set smtp_url = "smtp://<my_email>@smtp.gmail.com:587/"
set smtp_pass = "<my_password>"
set from = "<my_email>@gmail.com"
set realname = "<my_name>"
set sendmail="/usr/bin/msmtp"

set header_cache =~/.mutt/cache/headers
set message_cachedir =~/.mutt/cache/bodies
set certificate_file =~/.mutt/certificates

set folder = "imaps://imap.gmail.com:993"
set spoolfile = "+INBOX"
set postponed = "+[Gmail]/Drafts"
set trash = "imaps://imap.gmail.com[Gmail]/Trash"

#======================================================#
# Order of headers and what to show
hdr_order Date: From: User-Agent: X-Mailer \
          To: Cc: Reply-To: Subject:
ignore *
unignore Date: From: User-Agent: X-Mailer  \
         To: Cc: Reply-To: Subject:

#======================================================#
# which editor do you want to use? 
# vim of course!
set editor="vim -c 'set tw=70 et' '+/^$' "
set edit_headers          # See the headers when editing
```

and my `.msmtprc`

```
account default
host smtp.gmail.com
port 587
from "<my_email>@gmail.com"
tls on
tls_starttls on
tls_trust_file /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
auth on
user "<my_email>@gmail.com"
password "<my_password>"
logfile ~/.msmtp.log
```

now here's the really weird stuff... mutt is able to get new emails as well as when I postpone an email it saves it as a draft in gmail and uploads it to the gmail server. Thanks.

Comment: "now here's the really weird stuff... mutt is able to get new emails" - Getting new mails and saving drafts is done with IMAP against imap.gmail.com. So problems affecting the sending through smtp.gmail.com do not affect retrieving.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After many more days of searching I found the solution. I needed to change the smtp url to:

```
set smtp_url="smtps://<username>@smtp.gmail.com:465/"
```

emails send just fine now!

Comment: by the way, this question is better suited to && might've gotten more replies on: https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: In case it helps anybody: my `smtp_url` did not include a port and that worked fine from my home network. Later when I used the same computer but from a different network, I could not get neomutt to send messages until added `:587` explicitly.